# What does Preserve Editor Tracking Info do?

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online

I'm confused as to what the option in picture 1 does during web layer publishing. The dialog box in this picture is from ArcGIS Pro 3.1.0 in the "Publish as Web Layer" menu.

What I would **expect** is that the resulting AGOL web layer would have the editor tracking fields enabled, and the box in the picture 2 would come pre-checked. This picture is from the feature layer "Settings" tab in AGOL. However, my experimenting does not reveal that to be the case. If I want to see the data fields normally associated with edit-tracking (editor, date and time, etc.), I still have to manually check that box in picture 2, then turn on the fields in the Data tab of that feature layer's AGOL page.

What does "Preserve Editor Tracking Info" actually do?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This just stops the edit date and editor from being updated to the date the layer was uploaded to AGOL. So, if this isn't checked the edit date and editor will update to the person who uploaded the data to AGOL and the date the data was uploaded.

If it is checked it will preserve the original editor and and edit date and not update those fields to the date the data was uploaded to AGOL.

It does not have anything to do with keeping track of edits going forward. It only makes it so this data is not reset to the date the data was uploaded to AGOL. It essentially does the same thing as copying these fields to a text and date field that will no longer automatically update.